# Why have SQL databases like PostgresSQL and MySQL added JSON data types?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, json

I'm looking for scenarios in which storing a JSON object in a relational database would be useful.

Comment: For support NoSQL object.

Comment: My belated 2-cents: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Answer (score 2):

Anywhere you have or need [EAV table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), it's another way to solve the problem. Or anywhere you accept JSON, especially if the JSON is arbitrary.